# Iterating over different Objects which are ordered by index number

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I am currently working on a bigger project where I found a part of it which seems very ugly to me from the code.

I stripped out the algorithm and made a working code, so it can be reviewed.

I have a data structure which contains several containers with several different objects:

```
struct Data {
    std::vector<TypeA> a;
    std::vector<TypeB> b;
    std::vector<TypeC> c;
}
```

`TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC` are all different objects with different sizes in the real programm. The comman part is they all have a `no`:

```
struct TypeA {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

struct TypeB {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

struct TypeC {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};
```

All Containers are ordered by ascending `no`:

```
Data d;

d.a.push_back(TypeA{ 1, "1" , "11" });
d.c.push_back(TypeC{ 2, "2", "12" });
d.b.push_back(TypeB{ 3, "3", "13" });
d.a.push_back(TypeA{ 4, "4", "14" });
d.c.push_back(TypeC{ 5, "5", "15" });
d.b.push_back(TypeB{ 6, "6", "16" });
```

All Numbers are unique, e.g. there's no `no==1` in `b` or `c`. The index numbers are consecutive and fill the data structures.

I want to iterate over the whole `struct Data` by the `no` of the different data members and do something with the additional shared things the containers have.

To emphasize the ugliness, I sometimes print `data1` and the other time `data2` but the iteration is exactly the same.

How can the algorithm be improved?

My idea would be writing an custom iterator for `Data` which iterates by the `no`. But I don't know what is the best approach.

I'm open to any suggestions.

The complete code:

#### example.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct TypeA {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

struct TypeB {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

struct TypeC {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

// In reality TypeA, TypeB and TypeC are not exactly the same

struct Data {
    std::vector<TypeA> a;
    std::vector<TypeB> b;
    std::vector<TypeC> c;

    // In reality there are not only 3 values 
    // but > 20 to print consecutively by no

    void print_data_in_order_of_no();
    void print_data2_in_order_of_no();
};
```

```
void Data::print_data_in_order_of_no()
{
    enum class It_out {
        none,
        a,
        b,
        c,
    };

    auto it_a = a.begin();
    auto it_b = b.begin();
    auto it_c = c.begin();

    std::size_t current_no = 0;
    auto it_out = It_out::none;

    do {
        auto possible_new_no = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
        it_out = It_out::none;

        if (it_a != a.end() &&
            it_a->no > current_no &&
            it_a->no < possible_new_no) {

            possible_new_no = it_a->no;
            it_out = It_out::a;
        }
        if (it_b != b.end() &&
            it_b->no > current_no &&
            it_b->no < possible_new_no) {

            possible_new_no = it_b->no;
            it_out = It_out::b;
        }
        if (it_c != c.end() &&
            it_c->no > current_no &&
            it_c->no < possible_new_no) {

            possible_new_no = it_c->no;
            it_out = It_out::c;
        }

        current_no = possible_new_no;

        switch (it_out) {
        case It_out::a:
            std::cout << it_a->data << '\n';
            ++it_a;
            break;
        case It_out::b:
            std::cout << it_b->data << '\n';
            ++it_b;
            break;
        case It_out::c:
            std::cout << it_c->data << '\n';
            ++it_c;
            break;
        case It_out::none:
            break;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "void print_data_in_order_of_no()"
                "impossible enum type"
            );
        }
    } while (it_out != It_out::none);
}
```

```
void Data::print_data2_in_order_of_no()
{
    enum class It_out {
        none,
        a,
        b,
        c,
    };

    auto it_a = a.begin();
    auto it_b = b.begin();
    auto it_c = c.begin();

    std::size_t current_no = 0;
    auto it_out = It_out::none;

    do {
        auto possible_new_no = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
        it_out = It_out::none;

        if (it_a != a.end() &&
            it_a->no > current_no &&
            it_a->no < possible_new_no) {

            possible_new_no = it_a->no;
            it_out = It_out::a;
        }
        if (it_b != b.end() &&
            it_b->no > current_no &&
            it_b->no < possible_new_no) {

            possible_new_no = it_b->no;
            it_out = It_out::b;
        }
        if (it_c != c.end() &&
            it_c->no > current_no &&
            it_c->no < possible_new_no) {

            possible_new_no = it_c->no;
            it_out = It_out::c;
        }

        current_no = possible_new_no;

        switch (it_out) {
        case It_out::a:
            std::cout << it_a->data2 <<'\n';
            ++it_a;
            break;
        case It_out::b:
            std::cout << it_b->data2 << '\n';
            ++it_b;
            break;
        case It_out::c:
            std::cout << it_c->data2 << '\n';
            ++it_c;
            break;
        case It_out::none:
            break;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error(
                "void print_data2_in_order_of_no()"
                "impossible enum type"
            );
        }
    } while (it_out != It_out::none);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Data d;

    d.a.push_back(TypeA{1, "1" , "11"});
    d.a.push_back(TypeA{ 4, "4", "14" });

    d.b.push_back(TypeB{ 3, "3", "13" });
    d.b.push_back(TypeB{ 6, "6", "16" });

    d.c.push_back(TypeC{ 2, "2", "12" });
    d.c.push_back(TypeC{ 5, "5", "15" });


    d.print_data_in_order_of_no();

    d.print_data2_in_order_of_no();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

The code for review is the `Data` struct and its members.

Comment: Is `no` used for something else or just for indexing/identification? If the latter, move `no` out of `TypeX` and join `TypeA`, `TypeB`, `TypeC` into a separate structure and use this structure in the container.

Comment: its only used for indexing. So you mean like a struct which have  `TypeA` `TypeB` `TypeC`  were only one member is occupied at the time?

Comment: I think Cornholio meant something like a `std::vector<std::variant<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>>` (where those three types have no `no` member since they are all explicitly ordered inside the container).

Comment: I don't think he wants a `std::variant` here, since he needs all of the `TypeA, TypeB, TypeC` containers to be valid at the same time.

Comment: `std::variant` was exactly what i was looking for the whole day. In combination with std::visit i can perform any operation necessary.

Comment: i edited how the order of the elements come. in the real code the data comes consecutively with the index but as different data types. perfectly for the suggested `std::variant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, I found `std::variant` to be a good solution for my issue:

I also added a template visitor it can save writing a lot of visitors if in all data structures the same thing needs to get accessed.

```
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

struct TypeA {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

struct TypeB {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

struct TypeC {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    // more data member etc...
};

// In reality TypeA, TypeB and TypeC are not exactly the same

struct Data {
    std::vector<std::variant< TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>> abc;

    std::vector<TypeA> a;
    std::vector<TypeB> b;
    std::vector<TypeC> c;

    // In reality there are not only 3 values 
    // but > 20 to print consecutively by no
};

struct Visit_data
{
    std::string operator()(TypeA& a) const { return a.data; } 
    std::string operator()(TypeB& b) const { return b.data; }
    std::string operator()(TypeC& c) const { return c.data; }
};

struct Visit_data2
{
    std::string operator()(TypeA& a) const { return a.data2; }
    std::string operator()(TypeB& b) const { return b.data2; }
    std::string operator()(TypeC& c) const { return c.data2; }
};

struct Visit_template_data
{
    template<typename T>
    std::string operator()(T& a) const { return a.data; }
};

int main()
{
    Data d;

    d.abc.push_back(TypeA{ 1, "1" , "11"});
    d.abc.push_back(TypeC{ 2, "2", "12" });
    d.abc.push_back(TypeB{ 3, "3", "13" });
    d.abc.push_back(TypeA{ 4, "4", "14" });
    d.abc.push_back(TypeC{ 5, "5", "15" });
    d.abc.push_back(TypeB{ 6, "6", "16" });

    for (auto& x : d.abc) {
        std::cout << std::visit(Visit_data(), x);
    }
    for (auto& x : d.abc) {
        std::cout << std::visit(Visit_data2(), x);
    }

    for (auto& x : d.abc) {
        std::cout << std::visit(Visit_template_data(), x);
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using the Visitor pattern as well as Variant, but you totally beat me to it!  See also the [`std::visit` example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit#Example) on CPP Reference for a way to create a an overloaded visitor, which might help you.

Comment: You have no idea how I patted my head when i realized I could refactor many poorly and overly complicated parts in the code by switching to `std::variant`.